# Failed to resolve: 'com.squareup.retrofit2.converter-gson:2.3.0'

Tags: retrofit

I am trying to include `'com.squareup.retrofit2.converter-gson:2.3.0'`  using Android Studio 3.2 Canary 5

See image below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

as you can search in google, putting this worked, I hope it helps you too

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
```

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw39C.png)

Comment: implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'  
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

Comment: FYI searching ddg suggests this answer

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:<latest-version>'
```

The latest version can be found [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/converter-gson).

Answer (score 0):

Simply paste this instead  :

- implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
- implementation'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'

Answer (score 0):

Use (where is possible) the latest version, I had the same error but it looks like the retrofit 'com.squareup.retrofit2.converter-gson:2.3.0' **version 2.3.0** is deprecated.

This works for me:

```
//Retrofit2
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.2'
```

Source:

https://square.github.io/retrofit/

https://github.com/square/retrofit

Answer (score 0):

it works perfectly well.

```
//retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.8.1'
```

It gives/provides the latest repo you'll need.